# What's the chance of a collision in Python's secrets. compare_digest function?

Tags: python, security, hash, cryptography

The closest function I can find to a constant time compare in Python's standard library is [secrets.compare_digest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.compare_digest)

But it makes me wonder, if in the case of using it to verify a secret token:

- What's the chance of a collision? As in, what's the chance of a secret passed that doesn't match the correct token, but the function returns true? (Assuming that both strings passed are the same length)
- What's the length of secret token when it becomes pointless to make the secret longer, at least in terms of mitigating brute force attacks?

Comment: *"As in, what's the chance of a secret passed that doesn't match the correct token, but the function returns true?"* - Huh? Zero. What am I missing?

Comment: @KellyBundy To me, the function's name suggests it doesn't actually compare the bytes, but rather a digest of the bytes, so the output of a hash function run on the bytes. Hash functions can have collisions, i.e. where two different inputs of the function results in the same output. Say if compare_digest uses MD5, then https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value has some example collisions (so I suspect compare_digest does not use MD5!)

Comment: The description of the function says *"Return True if strings or bytes-like objects a and b are equal, otherwise False"*. Nothing about hashing. The given a and b are compared. They're supposed to already be digests, that's what the function name means.

Comment: Ah - so it is not appropriate to use the function on something that isn't a digest?

Comment: (I guess I'm now wondering why the function isn't called "constant_time_compare" or something like that)

Comment: The referenced `compare_digest` is even more direct, its doc saying right away *"Return `a == b`."*.

Comment: Well, sure you can use it for something else, but that's the intended usage. Yes, `constant_time_compare` might've been a better name.

Comment: I should've said *"The referenced **hmac**.compare_digest"*. Same function name, different module. The `secrets` module purely imports it from `hmac`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[secrets](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/secrets.py) uses [hmac](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/hmac.py) which uses [hashopenssl](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_hashopenssl.c). This uses the `_tscmp` function to compare things, which uses openssl's [CRYPTO_memcmp](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/CRYPTO_memcmp.html). The docs don't mention anything about the probability. I'm not good at reading the [assembly code commit](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/e33826f01bd78af76e0135c8dfab3387927a82bb#diff-0a0b507e81247614bd666f5fb9290f34034de26c8a86fa897b4e2ad7d02d91ed) but it doesn't look like it is doing anything other than directly comparing the memory. So I don't see why it would have a probability of collision, since hashing is not involved

As for the question of a brute force attack - assuming assume we did the comparison at max gpu bandwidth of a [modern gpu with 2TB/s](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/a100/), which is [1.6e+13 bits](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=2TB+to+bit&ia=answer), if we multiply that by 1 year of time, that is ~ 3.1e+7 seconds we get ~5e21 bits of comparison per year per gpu. log2(5e21) = 72 -> which means we could theoretically break a 72 bit key with a a gpu in 1 year. (This is likely not possible because gpus are not designed for this, but an asic could probably be made with this kind of performance). Going with the eough estimate of 72/yr/device -> you can simply double the number of devices or number of years per bit increased. (Or maybe you could add 1 to the number of years assuming efficiency doubles every year). Here, 128 bits gives 20 years of doubling efficiency + 1 billion gpus / 10,000 supercomputers.

Addidional note -> [top supercomputer flops](https://www.top500.org/lists/top500/2022/11/) is 1e18 per second = 100,000 gpus (it does have 8,730,112 cores or 136,408 amd 64c cpus...)

On impractical scales -> the universe contains maybe [1e82](https://www.universetoday.com/36302/atoms-in-the-universe/) atoms and a neucleon could last for [1e200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_far_future) years which is ~1e207 seconds. Assuming each atom can do a bit comparison in 1e-44 seconds (plank time), we could theoretically compute 1e333 bits. that's a keysize of 1106. I suspect a keysize of 1024 should be enough assuming the efficiency of turning the universe into a computer is 1e-24.

Comment: "So I don't see why it would have a probability of collision, since hashing is not involved" - so the name of the function, compare_digest, feels slightly misleading?

Comment: @MichalCharemza the [hmac docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html#hmac.HMAC.digest) does make it somewhat clearer that the it's just == but resistant to timing attacks.

Comment: What you are computing is preimage resistance, but collision resistance is a different calculation. Typically well-designed hash functions are collision resistant up to O(n\*\*0.5) for an output space of cardinality n.